# EOS Webcam Utility not working with Slack

Tags: webcam, streaming, canon, slack

I have installed the [EOS Webcam Utility](https://www.usa.canon.com/cameras/eos-webcam-utility) from the Canon website. After plugging in my camera (Canon M50 Mark II), it works great with OBS software, Google Hangouts and Skype, but not with Slack.

Slack seems not to recognize my video input, it just displays the EOS Webcam Utility logo, which makes me think is a Slack issue and not OS related.

Answer (score 3):

From the [EOS Webcam Utility website](https://canon.ca/dam/Brochures/ITCG/Canon-WebCam-Utility/Canon-WebCam-Utility-Instructions-Mac-Official-FINAL.pdf):

> EOS Webcam Utility software does not support apps downloaded from the App Store. Please download the application from the service provider’s website where available.

I did install Slack from the App Store. Then I just removed it from the Applications folder and then I downloaded the app from the Slack website and now it works perfectly. Lesson learned.